# HTTP response returns valid content-length header but no message body

Tags: apache-2.2, http, http-headers

I've recently found a very strange problem which I can't explain. After posting a HTTP request to our server occasionally the following response will occur:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Mon, 13 Apr 2015 10:00:53 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.16
Content-Length: 48
Keep-Alive: timeout=60, max=100
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: text/html
```

However as you can see there is no data in the message body even though the content-length field indicates there should be 48 bytes.

Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your application software makes this happen for some reason, and it is impossible to guess what makes it happen without knowing anything about the application software.

Comment: What sort of request results in this response?  `HEAD` requests, `POST` requests, or...?